# Почему нельзя запустить скрипт в планировщике

Tags: openserver

Я запускаю простейший скрипт *hello.php*:

```
echo "hello";
```

В консоли

```
e:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.3\php-win.exe -c e:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.3\php.ini -q -f e:\OpenServer\domains\unn.loc\hello.php>e:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\temp_aa.txt
```

без проблем создает файл `temp_aa.txt` и пишет 'hello'.

А если запустить в планировщике задач, то не пишет 'hello', файл не создается.

```
e:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.3\php-win.exe -c e:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.3\php.ini -q -f e:\OpenServer\domains\unn.loc\hello.php>e:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\temp_aa.txt
```

в логе

> 12 Oct 10:31:01 Start nnCron
>   12 Oct 10:31:01 Load cron.tab
>   12 Oct 10:32:00 Start: e:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.3\php-win.exe -c
>   e:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.3\php.ini -q -f
>   e:\OpenServer\domains\unn.loc\hello.php>e:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\temp_aa.txt
>   12 Oct 10:32:00 Start result: 0

Что я делаю «не так»?

Comment: В \*nix man cron написано:  `When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of  the
       crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the
       crontab, if such exists).`  Возможно в винде в OpenServer  поведение такое же и `hello` надо искать в почте?

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду папку \userdata\temp\email , то там все пусто.

Comment: Я думаю, что почта если почта не настроена, то это письмо у админа (в \*nix такие сообщения накапливаются у локального root)

Comment: у меня windows7. и куда на сей раз приходит, пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: Про винду не знаю. Не зря же я все время ссылаюсь на \*nix. Ждите специалистов по M$

Comment: То есть , я так понимаю, в линуксах, приходят на почту?

Comment: приходит туда, куда настроено. по умолчанию — пользователю, от имени которого выполнялось cron-задание. но к *ms/windows* всё это не имеет ровно никакого отношения. там и самого-то понятия «почта для пользователя» — просто нет.

Comment: спасибо, то есть не будет выводится в виндовсе, если запустишь скрипт в планировщике? Понятно, запустила так скрипт в консоли,без планировщика.